# Access a string value outside PageLoad(if(!Page.IsPostBack))

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to access value of a string outside the block of `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` in `PageLoad`.

I have declared `string sap1` `public`.

My Code is

```
     public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    string sap = "";
    string sap1;
    protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        TextBox1.Text = d.ToShortDateString(); 
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string q = d.ToShortDateString();
            string[] separators = { "-", "/" };
            string s = d.ToShortDateString();
            string[] words = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var word in words)
                sap = sap + word;

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {


                sap1 = "D" + sap;
                string query = "create table " + sap1 + " (Name varchar(50),ContentType 
       nvarchar(200),Data varbinary(MAX));";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            AddNewRow();
        } 
       protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         Response.Write(sap1);
       }
    }
```

I want to access the value of `sap1` outside the `PageLoad`. I want to use it for insert into Query.

Comment: Where have you initialized `sap` and `sap1`? Its not in the given piece of code.

Comment: @Shaharyar I have initialized above PageLoad but i haven't mentioned in code.. Sorry for that...

Comment: Please add a little more detail to your question. Where and how you declared the variables? Where have you initialized them? and where are you using them?

Comment: @Shaharyar i have edited the question. I am not getting the value of sap1 and i think it's because of if(!Page.IsPostback)..

Comment: Unlike, windows applications, the asp.net page object is destroyed once the page is rendered. So no matter, whether it is a global variable or a local variable, everything will be swallowed by the GC. If you need to keep some data, between postbacks (or as long as the user session is active) then you will have to keep it either in "Session" or "ViewState". There are several guidelines for when to use Viewstate and session. Please get in touch with Google :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [store the value of sap1 in a Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
Session["sap1"] = sap1;
```

Then retrieve it when you need it:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["sap1"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some declaration of this property outside of the Page_Load method

```
private string sap1;
```

and then you can access it in whole class. But be careful about ASP.NET page life cycle. You will have sap1 with value only after Page_Load. In the earlier stages of the page life cycle it will be null of course.

Comment: I have declared it publically but it's giving null value as you mentioned..
Please help..

Comment: In which method do you want to access it?

Comment: button click is PostBack action. So, you can't have initialized property sap1 if you set it in block if(!Page.IsPostback)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the if check `if(!Page.IsPostback)`. You need to calculate `sap` and `sap1` on every `PostBack`. So it'll available when you click on the button.

Just remove the condition `if(!Page.IsPostback)`.